# Convert MySQL date and time to datetime

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has 4 columns. Date login, date logout, time login, time logout.

How can I get the difference. I tried something like this;

```
SUM(TIMESTAMP(date_logout, time_logout) - TIMESTAMP(date_log, time_log))
```

However I'm getting a really really high number and I am unable to convert it to proper time. Any hints or clues? I didn't design the table btw :P

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add an example row so we can see the complete format of the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the diff in secounds:

```
SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(date_logout, time_logout)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(date_log, time_log)))
```

If you want the diff in days:

```
SUM(DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(date_logout, time_logout), TIMESTAMP(date_log, time_log)))
```

If you want the diff as HH:mm:ss

```
SUM(TIMEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(date_logout, time_logout), TIMESTAMP(date_log, time_log)))
```

Comment: Perfect! You've saved me the trouble of having to convert it from seconds too!

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the two value by using TIMEDIFF FUNCTION.

```
TIMEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(date_logout, time_logout) ,TIMESTAMP(date_log, time_log) )
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for but I marked the other question cause it had extra bits which were really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
TIMEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(date_logout, time_logout) , TIMESTAMP(date_log, time_log))
```